# Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument to unpark() was not a Thread

Tags: java, exception

**# tag:Fatal Exception: java.lag.IllegalArgumentException: Argument to unpack() was not a Thread Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument to unpark() was not a Thread at sun.misc.Unsafe.unpark(Unsafe.java) at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.unpark(:4) at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfws.zzx(zzfws.java:2) at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfws.zzc(zzfws.java:2) at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfzc.zze(zzfzc.java:1) at com.google.android.gms.intyour text*ernal.ads.zzfyn.run(zzfyn.java:8) at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzfzd.run(zzfzd.java:1) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(:79) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(:2) at java.lang.Thread.run(:4)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask